# How can I concatenate all the contents of a field in a list into a string?

Tags: c#

I have code:

```
var locales = await TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();
```

What I would like to do is to get all the values of Country and concatenate them together with a comma in between and place that in a string.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s = string.Join(",",locales.Select(locale => locale.Country))
```

Comment: Good suggestion with build-in function